# Crear un arreglo de documentos JSON válido a partir de un CSV

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, csv

Tengo un archivo con datos separados por *pipes*  o `|` de la siguiente forma:

```
FOLIO|estatus|causa_rechazo|mov_solicitado|mov_definitivo|fecha_tramite|fecha_rec_cecyrd|fecha_reg_cecyrd|fecha_cancelado_mac|fecha_rechazado|fecha_cancelado_mov_post|fecha_alta_pe|fecha_actual_pe|fecha_reinc_pe|fecha_existoso|fecha_lote_prod|fecha_listo_reimp|fecha_cpv_creada|fecha_registrada_mac|fecha_disponible|fecha_entregada|fecha_afecta_ln
1738163100001|RECHAZADO|TRAMITE CANCELADO EN MAC POR MOVIMIENTO POSTERIOR|INSCRIPCION||02/01/2017 08:09:45 a. m.|02/01/2017 08:26:37 a. m.|02/01/2017 10:08:24 a. m.|02/01/2017 10:08:24 a. m.|||||||||||||
1738163100002|ENTREGADA||CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO|CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO|02/01/2017 08:09:47 a. m.|02/01/2017 08:22:48 a. m.|02/01/2017 10:08:55 a. m.||||02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.|02/01/2017 10:08:07 a. m.||02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.|02/01/2017 05:01:53 p. m.||02/01/2017 05:01:40 p. m.|09/01/2017 09:35:05 a. m.|09/01/2017 09:49:48 a. m.|23/01/2017 08:53:56 a. m.|23/01/2017 10:44:24 a. m.
1738452100001|ENTREGADA||REPOSICION DE CREDENCIAL|REPOSICION DE CREDENCIAL|02/01/2017 08:13:18 a. m.|02/01/2017 08:15:42 a. m.|02/01/2017 10:08:30 a. m.||||02/01/2017 10:07:43 a. m.|02/01/2017 10:08:53 a. m.||02/01/2017 10:07:43 a. m.|02/01/2017 05:02:05 p. m.||02/01/2017 05:01:54 p. m.|06/01/2017 08:18:06 a. m.|06/01/2017 08:32:10 a. m.|28/01/2017 10:27:27 a. m.|29/01/2017 06:40:03 p. m.
```

Intento procesarlos con [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) para poder importarlos en MongoDB, por lo que hice este script que usa el módulo [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson):

```
'use strict'

const csvRegistros = 'registros.csv'
const csv = require('csvtojson')
const parametros = {
  delimiter: '|',
  noheader: false,
  headers: [
    "FOLIO", "estatus", "causa_rechazo", "mov_solicitado", "mov_definitivo",
    "fecha_tramite", "fecha_rec_cecyrd", "fecha_reg_cecyrd", "fecha_cancelado_mac",
    "fecha_rechazado", "fecha_cancelado_mov_post", "fecha_alta_pe", "fecha_actual_pe",
    "fecha_reinc_pe", "fecha_existoso", "fecha_lote_prod", "fecha_listo_reimp",
    "fecha_cpv_creada", "fecha_registrada_mac", "fecha_disponible", "fecha_entregada",
    "fecha_afecta_ln"
  ],
  checkColumn: true,
  workerNum: 1
}

csv(parametros)
  .fromFile(csvRegistros)
  .on('json', (jsonObj) => {
    console.log(jsonObj)
  })
```

No escribe ningún archivo, porque no se cómo hacerlo todavía, así que lo ejecuto de la siguiente manera:

```
node .\convertidor.js > .\test.json
```

Y mi salida es así (borro algunos campos por brevedad):

```
{ FOLIO: '1738163100001',
  estatus: 'RECHAZADO',
  causa_rechazo: 'TRAMITE CANCELADO EN MAC POR MOVIMIENTO POSTERIOR',
  mov_solicitado: 'INSCRIPCION',
  mov_definitivo: '',
  fecha_tramite: '02/01/2017 08:09:45 a. m.',
  fecha_rec_cecyrd: '02/01/2017 08:26:37 a. m.',
  fecha_reg_cecyrd: '02/01/2017 10:08:24 a. m.',
  fecha_cancelado_mac: '02/01/2017 10:08:24 a. m.',
  ...
  fecha_disponible: '',
  fecha_entregada: '',
  fecha_afecta_ln: '' }
{ FOLIO: '1738163100002',
  estatus: 'ENTREGADA',
  causa_rechazo: '',
  mov_solicitado: 'CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO',
  mov_definitivo: 'CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO',
  fecha_tramite: '02/01/2017 08:09:47 a. m.',
  fecha_rec_cecyrd: '02/01/2017 08:22:48 a. m.',
  fecha_reg_cecyrd: '02/01/2017 10:08:55 a. m.',
  fecha_cancelado_mac: '',
  ...
  fecha_disponible: '09/01/2017 09:49:48 a. m.',
  fecha_entregada: '23/01/2017 08:53:56 a. m.',
  fecha_afecta_ln: '23/01/2017 10:44:24 a. m.' }
```

La salida, parece correcta, pero cuando la paso por un [validador](http://jsonlint.com/) obtengo el error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   FOLIO: '173816310000
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Hay un [demo](http://keyangxiang.com/csvtojson/) que produce una salida correcta: un *arreglo* de *objetos*, según la [definición de JSON](http://www.json.org/json-es.html).

### Problema

Mi objetivo **importar los datos a MongoDB usando Node.js con un arreglo de documentos en JSON** . Este módulo me interesó porque permite usar multihilos y tengo algunas cuantas decenas de miles de registros que procesar, pero cualquier alternativa que me permita lograr el objetivo se agradece.

> #### Notas
>
> - Tengo un problema con las fechas, pero es tema de otra pregunta. Por el momento, esta pregunta se centra en crear el documento JSON.
> - Estoy usando Windows 8 para este ejemplo, aunque puedo usar Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 17.04 o macOS Sierra 10.
> - El servidor MongoDB es 2.6.10 y corre en una máquina con Ubuntu Linux 16.04

#### Actualización

Tal como comenta Trauma en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/65413/638), el primer paso es usar una salida correcta usando `JSON.Stringify`, por lo que ahora el script se ve así:

```
csv(parametros)
  .fromFile(csvRegistros)
  .on('json', (jsonObj) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj))
  })
```

La salida, sin embargo **no es válida** porque no es un arreglo de objetos:

```
{"FOLIO":"1738163100001","estatus":"RECHAZADO","causa_rechazo":"TRAMITE CANCELADO EN MAC POR MOVIMIENTO POSTERIOR","mov_solicitado":"INSCRIPCION","mov_definitivo":"","fecha_tramite":"02/01/2017 08:09:45 a. m.","fecha_rec_cecyrd":"02/01/2017 08:26:37 a. m.","fecha_reg_cecyrd":"02/01/2017 10:08:24 a. m.","fecha_cancelado_mac":"02/01/2017 10:08:24 a. m.","fecha_rechazado":"","fecha_cancelado_mov_post":"","fecha_alta_pe":"","fecha_actual_pe":"","fecha_reinc_pe":"","fecha_existoso":"","fecha_lote_prod":"","fecha_listo_reimp":"","fecha_cpv_creada":"","fecha_registrada_mac":"","fecha_disponible":"","fecha_entregada":"","fecha_afecta_ln":""}
{"FOLIO":"1738163100002","estatus":"ENTREGADA","causa_rechazo":"","mov_solicitado":"CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO","mov_definitivo":"CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO","fecha_tramite":"02/01/2017 08:09:47 a. m.","fecha_rec_cecyrd":"02/01/2017 08:22:48 a. m.","fecha_reg_cecyrd":"02/01/2017 10:08:55 a. m.","fecha_cancelado_mac":"","fecha_rechazado":"","fecha_cancelado_mov_post":"","fecha_alta_pe":"02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.","fecha_actual_pe":"02/01/2017 10:08:07 a. m.","fecha_reinc_pe":"","fecha_existoso":"02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.","fecha_lote_prod":"02/01/2017 05:01:53 p. m.","fecha_listo_reimp":"","fecha_cpv_creada":"02/01/2017 05:01:40 p. m.","fecha_registrada_mac":"09/01/2017 09:35:05 a. m.","fecha_disponible":"09/01/2017 09:49:48 a. m.","fecha_entregada":"23/01/2017 08:53:56 a. m.","fecha_afecta_ln":"23/01/2017 10:44:24 a. m."}
{"FOLIO":"1738452100001","estatus":"ENTREGADA","causa_rechazo":"","mov_solicitado":"REPOSICION DE CREDENCIAL","mov_definitivo":"REPOSICION DE CREDENCIAL","fecha_tramite":"02/01/2017 08:13:18 a. m.","fecha_rec_cecyrd":"02/01/2017 08:15:42 a. m.","fecha_reg_cecyrd":"02/01/2017 10:08:30 a. m.","fecha_cancelado_mac":"","fecha_rechazado":"","fecha_cancelado_mov_post":"","fecha_alta_pe":"02/01/2017 10:07:43 a. m.","fecha_actual_pe":"02/01/2017 10:08:53 a. m.","fecha_reinc_pe":"","fecha_existoso":"02/01/2017 10:07:43 a. m.","fecha_lote_prod":"02/01/2017 05:02:05 p. m.","fecha_listo_reimp":"","fecha_cpv_creada":"02/01/2017 05:01:54 p. m.","fecha_registrada_mac":"06/01/2017 08:18:06 a. m.","fecha_disponible":"06/01/2017 08:32:10 a. m.","fecha_entregada":"28/01/2017 10:27:27 a. m.","fecha_afecta_ln":"29/01/2017 06:40:03 p. m."}
```

Nótese que no están separados por comas, y por supuesto no es un array, que debería ser así:

```
[ {trámite}, {trámite}, ..., {trámite}]
```

Comment: ¿ Esa es la salida **literal**, con todas sus comillas `'` y `"`, o la has editado ?  eso **no** es un JSON.

Comment: @Trauma: Todo es literal... lo único que hice fue borrar campos de fechas... y uno de los tres registros de ejemplos, pero así sale.

Comment: ¿ Estas usando `JSON.stringify( )`, o `console.log( )` ?

Comment: Uso `console.log(jsonObj)` para mostrar la salida de `jsonObj` que es el objeto que se le pasa a la callback del método `on()` de `csv`

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando `console.log( )`.

**Cámbialo** por `JSON.stringify( )`:

```
csv(parametros)
  .fromFile(csvRegistros)
 .on('json', (jsonObj) => {
 console.log(JSON.stringify( jsonObj ) )
})
```

`console.log( )` **no** convierte un *objeto* en una representación JSON válida; se limita a mostrarnos el *objeto* en un formato *entendible*, pero **no conforme** a lo que se espera de un JSON.

Comment: Cierto. Ahora sale una sola línea cada registro, pero me sigue marcando un error, la coma que separa cada objeto. Podría procesar el archivo con un ciclo `for` y subir línea por línea, pero me gustaría que la salida fuera un _arreglo de objetos JSON_. ¿Debo modificar mi pregunta?

Comment: La doc indica que puedes usar `toArrayString: true` como opción para ahorrarte el `stringify( )`, pero **no** dice nada sobre separador para múltiples objetos. Podrías probar con `eol: ",\n"` (coma, barra, n), por si *cuela*, o me temo que tendrás que hacer lo que comentas y usar un bucle.

Comment: Intenta utilizando la misma librería que se usa en la página de demo; ábrela, para ver el código fuente, y [mira el link que usa internamente](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/e963d121/dist/csvtojson.js). Tal vez el repositorio no esté actualizado.

Comment: O *reemplaza* los finales de objeto, después de tener la cadena, con `String.replace( )`. Cambia `}{` por `},{`.

Answer (score 1):

A tener en mente:

1. Reemplazar los pipes | por comas, porque así es un archivo delimitado por comas (CSV) válido.
2. El formato JSON es "Clave": "Valor", nótese las comillas dobles.
3. Una vez tengas los formatos arreglados podrás utilizar las librerías que desees.

He trabajado tu data con los puntos anteriores:

```
FOLIO,estatus,causa_rechazo,mov_solicitado,mov_definitivo,fecha_tramite,fecha_rec_cecyrd,fecha_reg_cecyrd,fecha_cancelado_mac,fecha_rechazado,fecha_cancelado_mov_post,fecha_alta_pe,fecha_actual_pe,fecha_reinc_pe,fecha_existoso,fecha_lote_prod,fecha_listo_reimp,fecha_cpv_creada,fecha_registrada_mac,fecha_disponible,fecha_entregada,fecha_afecta_ln
1738163100001,RECHAZADO,TRAMITE CANCELADO EN MAC POR MOVIMIENTO POSTERIOR,INSCRIPCION,,02/01/2017 08:09:45 a. m.,02/01/2017 08:26:37 a. m.,02/01/2017 10:08:24 a. m.,02/01/2017 10:08:24 a. m.,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1738163100002,ENTREGADA,,CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO,CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO,02/01/2017 08:09:47 a. m.,02/01/2017 08:22:48 a. m.,02/01/2017 10:08:55 a. m.,,,,02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.,02/01/2017 10:08:07 a. m.,,02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.,02/01/2017 05:01:53 p. m.,,02/01/2017 05:01:40 p. m.,09/01/2017 09:35:05 a. m.,09/01/2017 09:49:48 a. m.,23/01/2017 08:53:56 a. m.,23/01/2017 10:44:24 a. m.
1738452100001,ENTREGADA,,REPOSICION DE CREDENCIAL,REPOSICION DE CREDENCIAL,02/01/2017 08:13:18 a. m.,02/01/2017 08:15:42 a. m.,02/01/2017 10:08:30 a. m.,,,,02/01/2017 10:07:43 a. m.,02/01/2017 10:08:53 a. m.,,02/01/2017 10:07:43 a. m.,02/01/2017 05:02:05 p. m.,,02/01/2017 05:01:54 p. m.,06/01/2017 08:18:06 a. m.,06/01/2017 08:32:10 a. m.,28/01/2017 10:27:27 a. m.,29/01/2017 06:40:03 p. m.
```

Ahora mediante la herramienta: http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json y definiendo que la separación es mediante comas, tenemos el siguiente JSON:

```
[
  {
    "FOLIO": 1738163100001,
    "estatus": "RECHAZADO",
    "causa_rechazo": "TRAMITE CANCELADO EN MAC POR MOVIMIENTO POSTERIOR",
    "mov_solicitado": "INSCRIPCION",
    "mov_definitivo": "",
    "fecha_tramite": "02/01/2017 08:09:45 a. m.",
    "fecha_rec_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 08:26:37 a. m.",
    "fecha_reg_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 10:08:24 a. m.",
    "fecha_cancelado_mac": "02/01/2017 10:08:24 a. m.",
    "fecha_rechazado": "",
    "fecha_cancelado_mov_post": "",
    "fecha_alta_pe": "",
    "fecha_actual_pe": "",
    "fecha_reinc_pe": "",
    "fecha_existoso": "",
    "fecha_lote_prod": "",
    "fecha_listo_reimp": "",
    "fecha_cpv_creada": "",
    "fecha_registrada_mac": "",
    "fecha_disponible": "",
    "fecha_entregada": "",
    "fecha_afecta_ln": ""
  },
  {
    "FOLIO": 1738163100002,
    "estatus": "ENTREGADA",
    "causa_rechazo": "",
    "mov_solicitado": "CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO",
    "mov_definitivo": "CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO",
    "fecha_tramite": "02/01/2017 08:09:47 a. m.",
    "fecha_rec_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 08:22:48 a. m.",
    "fecha_reg_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 10:08:55 a. m.",
    "fecha_cancelado_mac": "",
    "fecha_rechazado": "",
    "fecha_cancelado_mov_post": "",
    "fecha_alta_pe": "02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.",
    "fecha_actual_pe": "02/01/2017 10:08:07 a. m.",
    "fecha_reinc_pe": "",
    "fecha_existoso": "02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.",
    "fecha_lote_prod": "02/01/2017 05:01:53 p. m.",
    "fecha_listo_reimp": "",
    "fecha_cpv_creada": "02/01/2017 05:01:40 p. m.",
    "fecha_registrada_mac": "09/01/2017 09:35:05 a. m.",
    "fecha_disponible": "09/01/2017 09:49:48 a. m.",
    "fecha_entregada": "23/01/2017 08:53:56 a. m.",
    "fecha_afecta_ln": "23/01/2017 10:44:24 a. m."
  },
  {
    "FOLIO": 1738452100001,
    "estatus": "ENTREGADA",
    "causa_rechazo": "",
    "mov_solicitado": "REPOSICION DE CREDENCIAL",
    "mov_definitivo": "REPOSICION DE CREDENCIAL",
    "fecha_tramite": "02/01/2017 08:13:18 a. m.",
    "fecha_rec_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 08:15:42 a. m.",
    "fecha_reg_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 10:08:30 a. m.",
    "fecha_cancelado_mac": "",
    "fecha_rechazado": "",
    "fecha_cancelado_mov_post": "",
    "fecha_alta_pe": "02/01/2017 10:07:43 a. m.",
    "fecha_actual_pe": "02/01/2017 10:08:53 a. m.",
    "fecha_reinc_pe": "",
    "fecha_existoso": "02/01/2017 10:07:43 a. m.",
    "fecha_lote_prod": "02/01/2017 05:02:05 p. m.",
    "fecha_listo_reimp": "",
    "fecha_cpv_creada": "02/01/2017 05:01:54 p. m.",
    "fecha_registrada_mac": "06/01/2017 08:18:06 a. m.",
    "fecha_disponible": "06/01/2017 08:32:10 a. m.",
    "fecha_entregada": "28/01/2017 10:27:27 a. m.",
    "fecha_afecta_ln": "29/01/2017 06:40:03 p. m."
  }
]
```

Comment: ¿Es necesario cambiar los pipes? Seguro que puedo hacerlo, pero agregaría tiempo, tomando en cuenta que sumaría millones de reemplazos. Literal, millones de `|` que habría que cambiar por `,`.

Comment: ¿Es necesario cambiar los pipes? -No, siempre y cuando te entreguen los registros CSV (Comma-separated values) en su respectivo formato.
Seguro que puedo hacerlo -¡Por su puesto! //Otra solución es que revises la librería https://github.com/martindrapeau/csvjson-app/blob/master/js/src/csv2json.js y la modifiques para que te traduzca los pipes :D el código está completo

Comment: Oh, además es una herramienta en línea. El archivo de donde salió el ejemplo, tiene unos 40 mil registros y pesa poco mas de 40 megas. Pero es el mas pequeño de todos los que tengo. Tiene una herramienta CLI que usa PHP: https://github.com/martindrapeau/csvjson-app

Comment: No me van a cambiar el formato de datos ='(

Comment: vamo al chat hermano

Answer (score 1):

Estimado **@toledano**, lo que ocurre es que el validador que usas ([jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)) se apega estrictamente a la sintaxis del **JSON** que es:

Los datos están en pares de nombre / valor.
Los datos se separan por **comas (aquí es donde ocurre el error)**.
Los Objetos se definen con llaves.
Las Matrices se definen con corchetes.

**JavaScript** no es tan estricto y es por ello que da por valido tu **JSON**, miestras que [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) no lo da por valido.

Por otro lado los archivos **CSV** "normalmente" usan como separador de campo la "," en tu caso no es necesario cambiar dicho delimitador ya que la herramienta para convertir te permite indicar el separador de campo que vas a usar, en este caso "|" (*pipes*).

ahora bien, el error que se presenta con tu **JSON** que separa los **String** con comillas simples pudiera deberse a que tu archivo "**CSV**" tampoco cumple con el principio de encerrar los "**String**" con comillas dobles (ej:**"Pedro Perez"**).

Te recomiendo que pruebes convirtiendo tu archivo **CSV** para que cumpla con el requisito de que *todo campo string debe estar encerrado con comillas dobles*.

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte, Saludos!! ;)).

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar creo que el archivo delimitado por **pipes** no es CSV.

El módulo seleccionado, afortunadamente, permite seleccionar el separador a utilizar. Básicamente el script original es correcto, solo hay que hacer ligeras modificaciones para obtener los resultados deseados.

Primero, la instalación del módulo. En mi caso use `yarn`.

```
$ yarn add --dev csvtojson
```

De este modo esta disponible en el script.

En este archivo hay algunos cambios que mejoran el original, primero presento el script final (para esta pregunta):

```
'use strict'

const csvRegistros = 'tramites.csv'
const csv = require('csvtojson')
const fs = require('fs')

const parametros = {
  delimiter: '|',
  headers: [
    "FOLIO", "estatus", "causa_rechazo", "mov_solicitado", "mov_definitivo",
    "fecha_tramite", "fecha_rec_cecyrd", "fecha_reg_cecyrd", "fecha_cancelado_mac",
    "fecha_rechazado", "fecha_cancelado_mov_post", "fecha_alta_pe", "fecha_actual_pe",
    "fecha_reinc_pe", "fecha_existoso", "fecha_lote_prod", "fecha_listo_reimp",
    "fecha_cpv_creada", "fecha_registrada_mac", "fecha_disponible", "fecha_entregada",
    "fecha_afecta_ln"
  ],
  checkColumn: true,
  flatKeys: true
}

csv(parametros)
  .fromFile(csvRegistros)
  .on('end_parsed', (jsonObj) => {
    fs.writeFile("prueba.json", JSON.stringify(jsonObj), (err) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      console.log('Se guardó el archivo');
    })
  })
```

El script hace uso del módulo `fs` para crear el archivo de salida. Así que se importa para tenerlo listo, junto con el nombre del archivo de entrada y el módulo que hace la conversión.

```
const csvRegistros = 'tramites.csv'
const csv = require('csvtojson')
const fs = require('fs')
```

A continuación, se definen los parámetros que juegan un papel clave en el desempeño del archivo, veamos:

- `delimiter: '|'`  - me permite usar el carácter *pipe* como separador o delimitador de campos. Por cuestiones de rendimiento, es mejor indicarlo, ya que de otro modo, `csvtojson` tratará de adivinarlo.
- `headers` - me permite indicar los encabezados de columna, que conformarán en los nombres de campos de los objetos JSON.
- `check column: true` - me asegura que cada registro tiene el número de columnas correcto, coincidiendo con los encabezados.
- `flatKeys: true` - el módulo busca de forma que los datos estén anidados, pero este archivo no. Seleccionar adecuadamente correctamente este parámetro tiene un enorme impacto en el desempeño del script, como veremos más adelante.

El script funciona de la siguiente manera, primero creamos el objeto `csv()` con los parámetros y el origen de los datos:

```
csv(parametros)
  .fromFile(csvRegistros)
```

esto crea un *stream*, es decir un flujo de datos al que podemos aplicarle diferentes acciones.

Para esta pregunta, la única acción de este flujo, se activa en el evento `end_parsed` que ocurre cuando se termina de convertir la fuente de datos.

```
  .on('end_parsed', (jsonObj) => {
    fs.writeFile("prueba.json", JSON.stringify(jsonObj), (err) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      console.log('Se guardó el archivo');
    })
  })
```

Lo que ocurre dentro de este evento es que el objeto `jsonObj`, que **ya contiene** el resultado del archivo procesado, se escribe en el archivo de salida.

La salida es un *arreglo* de objetos JSON, en este caso es un arreglo de *tramites* y tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
[ {tramite1}, {tramite2}, {tramite3}, ..., {tramiteN} ]
```

Por último, quiero comentar sobre el parámetro `flatKeys`. En archivo de pruebas contiene un poco más de 40 mil trámites:

```
 ~/Proyectos/tramites $ wc -l tramites.csv 
   40797 tramites.csv
```

Cuando `flatKeys` está en `false`, como es su valor por omisión, el archivo se procesa en unos 9 segundos.

```
 ~/Proyectos/tramites $ time node convertir.js
Se guardó el archivo
node convertir.js  8.53s user 0.36s system 92% cpu 9.635 total
```

Cuando `flatKeys` está en `true`, el desempeño mejora significativamente:

```
 ~/Proyectos/tramites $ time node convertir.js
Se guardó el archivo
node convertir.js  1.33s user 0.26s system 61% cpu 2.572 total
```

**Casi un 75% de mejora.**

El resultado es válido y es lo que queríamos encontrar.

Comment: me alegra que hayas solucionado con las tecnologías que deseabas, que sigan los éxitos hermano! :D