# Sustitución condicionada en objetos JSON

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Tengo un montón de objetos JSON de este tipo.

```
{
    "FOLIO": "1738163100002",
    "estatus": "ENTREGADA",
    "causa_rechazo": "",
    "mov_solicitado": "CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO",
    "mov_definitivo": "CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO",
    "fecha_tramite": "02/01/2017 08:09:47 a. m.",
    "fecha_rec_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 08:22:48 a. m.",
    "fecha_reg_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 10:08:55 a. m.",
    "fecha_cancelado_mac": "",
    "fecha_rechazado": "",
    "fecha_cancelado_mov_post": "",
    "fecha_alta_pe": "02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.",
    "fecha_actual_pe": "02/01/2017 10:08:07 a. m.",
    "fecha_reinc_pe": "",
    "fecha_existoso": "02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.",
    "fecha_lote_prod": "02/01/2017 05:01:53 p. m.",
    "fecha_listo_reimp": "",
    "fecha_cpv_creada": "02/01/2017 05:01:40 p. m.",
    "fecha_registrada_mac": "09/01/2017 09:35:05 a. m.",
    "fecha_disponible": "09/01/2017 09:49:48 a. m.",
    "fecha_entregada": "23/01/2017 08:53:56 a. m.",
    "fecha_afecta_ln": "23/01/2017 10:44:24 a. m."
}
```

Quiero cambiar las fechas porque la terminación actual `a. m.` y `p. m.` me causa problemas para procesar el archivo en diferentes operaciones.

Para recorrer el objeto uso el método `forEach()` de [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach)

```
_.forEach(tramite, (valor, clave) => {
  console.log(valor)
})
```

Mi problema es que no sé como buscar y reemplazar con JavaScript.

Para buscar, quiero usar esta expresión:

```
(([a|p])\. m\.)
```

Esta crea dos grupos, el primero puede contener `a. m.` o `p. m.` y el grupo dos, solo contiene la `a` o la `p`.

De modo que quiero que cuando el grupo 2 `==='a'` se sustituya **todo** el grupo 1 por `AM`.  Obvio, usar `PM` cuando el grupo 2 sea `==='p'`.

#### Pregunta

Como puedo sustituir **en JavaScript** `a. m.` por `AM` y `p. m.` por `PM`. Quisiera aprender a usar el operador ternario (creo que es `A ? B : C`).

> ### Nota
>
> - Si tienen alguna alternativa, y si tienen tiempo, le ruego que la expliquen de la forma mas didáctica posible.
> - También me gustaría que, si me proponen alguna alternativa, consideren el desempeño del script, por ejemplo el archivo de pruebas tiene 40 mil registros, lo que haría un poco mas de medio millón de sustituciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lodash tiene un metodo de replace según la documentación.

[Documentación lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#replace)

Te pongo un jsfiddle con un ejemplo de como hacerlo, espero sea de tu ayuda.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/mmh6zg7b/)

Es lo que se hace para el replace

El loop recorre el objeto, se ocupa el método de lodash [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#includes) que retorna true o false para evaluar un string en común en este caso el valor del objeto, se ocuparon los operadores [ternarios](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator) que no es más que una estructura de control parecida a if y else por lo tanto se pone la primera condición a evaluar que traducido en if else queda de esta manera: dónde ? es if y : es else.

If Else

```
_.forEach(data, (valor, clave) => {
    var final = ''
    if( _.includes(valor, 'a. m.') ){
        final = _.replace(valor, 'a. m.', 'AM');
     }else if(_.includes(valor, 'p. m.')){
        final = _.replace(valor, 'p. m.', 'PM');
     }else{
        final = valor
     }

  console.log(final)
})
```

Ternario

```
_.forEach(data, (valor, clave) => {
 var final =  _.includes(valor, 'a. m.') ? _.replace(valor, 'a. m.', 'AM') : _.includes(valor, 'p. m.') ? _.replace(valor, 'p. m.', 'PM') : valor;
  console.log(final)
})
```

Comment: Oye, pero entonces ¿tendría que aplicarlo dos veces, una para AM y otra para PM? Son 17 campos de fecha por registro... si tengo que hacerlo dos veces en mi archivo de pruebas tendría que hacer mas 1.36 millones de búsquedas.

Comment: Entonces te sugiero hacer esto desde tu base de datos o desde donde obtengas estos datos, para no hacerlo en el front end

Comment: Gracias. Lo hago en node y estoy trabajando con el origen, que no puedo cambiar. Mira: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65412/ PD Ya cloné tu fiddle... gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Tambien puedes meter como segundo parámetro una expresión regular para que se haga una sola vez el replace, la cuestión aquí es como hacer la expresión regular para cambiar a. m. p. m. por ''

Comment: Mira puedes usar esto _.replace(valor, new RegExp('a. m.|p. m.',"g"), '');

Comment: Puedes volver a revisar el jsfiddle ya obtiene el resultado que esperas

Comment: Lodash tiene igual un método para saber si el string contiene ciertos caracteres y con eso se puede evaluar el string y hacer el replace que quieras.

Comment: Jorge, la alternativa que propones es excelente. ¿Sería mucho pedir que, pensando no solo en mí, sino en cualquier visitante que llegue buscando tu respuesta, nos explicaras como funciona tu solución? Una explicación sencilla es suficiente. La idea es que no nos quedemos solo con usar sin comprender. Confirmo que tu propuesta funciona y con un desempeño excelente.

Comment: Listo espero que sea entendible, saludos!!

Answer (score 4):

#### Pasar una función como parámetro de String.replace()

Cuando el reemplazo depende para cada caso, no se usa un texto en el reemplazo, se asigna una función (un *callback*).

- Ver [Especificando una función con un parámetro](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace#Especificando_una_funci.C3.B3n_con_un_par.C3.A1metro) de `String.prototype.replace()`.

Un ejemplo sencillo sería:

```js
let regex = /\d+/g,
    texto = "10,20,30",
    resultado;
    
resultado = texto.replace(regex,function(match){return parseInt(match,10) + 5;});

console.log(resultado);  // => 15,25,35
```

---

#### Recorrer un objeto reemplazando todos los valores

Para tu caso específico, algunas aclaraciones:

- No se usa `|` dentro de una clase de caracteres, a menos que se quiera que `[a|p]` coincida con `a`, `|`, o `p`. Simplemente sería `[ap]`.
- No es necesario usar 2 grupos, con sólo capturar la primera letra alcanza: `([ap])\. m\.`

```js
let tramite = {
    "FOLIO": "1738163100002",
    "estatus": "ENTREGADA",
    "causa_rechazo": "",
    "mov_solicitado": "CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO",
    "mov_definitivo": "CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO",
    "fecha_tramite": "02/01/2017 08:09:47 a. m.",
    "fecha_rec_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 08:22:48 a. m.",
    "fecha_reg_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 10:08:55 a. m.",
    "fecha_cancelado_mac": "",
    "fecha_rechazado": "",
    "fecha_cancelado_mov_post": "",
    "fecha_alta_pe": "02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.",
    "fecha_actual_pe": "02/01/2017 10:08:07 a. m.",
    "fecha_reinc_pe": "",
    "fecha_existoso": "02/01/2017 10:08:09 a. m.",
    "fecha_lote_prod": "02/01/2017 05:01:53 p. m.",
    "fecha_listo_reimp": "",
    "fecha_cpv_creada": "02/01/2017 05:01:40 p. m.",
    "fecha_registrada_mac": "09/01/2017 09:35:05 a. m.",
    "fecha_disponible": "09/01/2017 09:49:48 a. m.",
    "fecha_entregada": "23/01/2017 08:53:56 a. m.",
    "fecha_afecta_ln": "23/01/2017 10:44:24 a. m."
}

let regexAMPM = /([ap])\. m\./;

Object.keys(tramite).map(  //recorrer todo el objeto
    clave => {
        tramite[clave] = tramite[clave].replace(
            regexAMPM,
            (match, grupo1) => grupo1 == "a" ? "AM" : "PM"
        );
    }
);

console.log(tramite);
```

Alternativamente, se podría devolver el valor sin usar un operador ternario:

```
(match, grupo1) => grupo1.toUpperCase() + "M"
```

**Eficiencia:**

En términos de eficiencia, considerando que vas a usar esta sustitución en muchos objetos, lo ideal es construir el regex por fuera del bucle, 1 sola vez. Es decir, llamando a

```
let regexAMPM = /([ap])\. m\./;
```

una única vez antes de recorrer todos tus registros.

---

#### Con lodash

Viendo que estás usando lodash, para recorrer el objeto podríamos usar [_.mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues).

```js
let tramite = {
    "mov_definitivo": "CAMBIO DE DOMICILIO",
    "fecha_tramite": "02/01/2017 08:09:47 a. m.",
    "fecha_rec_cecyrd": "02/01/2017 08:22:48 a. m.",
    "fecha_lote_prod": "02/01/2017 05:01:53 p. m.",
    "fecha_listo_reimp": ""
}

let regexAMPM = /([ap])\. m\./;

tramite = _.mapValues(
    tramite,
    valor => valor.replace(
        regexAMPM,
        (match, grupo1) => grupo1 == "a" ? "AM" : "PM"
    )
);

console.log(tramite);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias... en términos de desempeño, la primera opción se ejecuta en 3.8xx seg y la segunda 4.2xx seg... milésimas mas, milésimas menos.

Comment: Es bueno saberlo, intuitivamente hubiese apostado por la otra.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal esta?

```
var fechas = ['10:15 a. m.','10:00 a. m.','10:15 p.m.']

for(var i = 0; i < fechas.length;i++)
  {
    var limpios = fechas[i].replace(/(a\.\s*m\.|p\.\s*m\.)/,'');
    console.log(limpios);
  }
```

Tambien en [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/tihofikozu/edit?js,console) y [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PLUtKf/2)

Explicacion

```
( = captura en grupo

a\. = donde tenga la letra `a.`

\s* = 0 o mas espacios

m\. = seguido de `m.` 

| = or

p\. = donde tenga la letra `p.`

\s* = 0 o mas espacios

m\. = seguido de `m.`

) = cierre captura grupo
```

Comment: Gracias. Pero debo aclarar que lo que necesito es que cuando el timestamp termine en `a. m.` se sustituya por `AM` y cuando termine en `p. m.` se cambie a `PM`. En tu propuesta, se elimina la terminación, lo que causaría muchos problemas.

Comment: Tienes razon, voy a editarla. GRACIAS POR LA OBSERVACION!